# Define NaN in portable C without "error C2124: divide or mod by zero"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2022

I have an old legacy code written in pure C. It's crossplatform. I need to define a NaN constant in it. My approach was:
`const double _NAN = 0.0/0.0;`
Unfortunately when I tried to build the code on Win machine (VS 2022) I've got `"error C2124: divide or mod by zero"`.

I'm pretty sure there is a parameter for parameter for MSVC compiler that disables it, but that's a public project and MS VS is only one of IDE which could be used to build it. And I don't want ask users to change defaults in a specific environment.

I guess I could use HEX value for NaN but suppose I'll face with endiannes... Which imply i'll need to detect endiannes in portable way.

Are there any better options to define NaN for double in C in a crossplatform way?

Comment: I don't now how standard it is, but besides the `NAN` macro mentioned in the answers, at least some platforms provide a `nan()` function for constructing NaNs.  It takes a `char *` parameter that seems to let you specify the "payload" for the NaN: `nan("1")`, `nan("0x800000")`, etc).  `man 3 nan` might tell you more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include `<math.h>` and use `NAN`. C 1999 and C 2018 7.12 5 both say:

> The macro
>
> `NAN`
>
> is defined if and only if the implementation supports quiet NaNs for the `float` type. It expands to a constant expression of type `float` representing a quiet NaN.

You can use it for the `double` type, and, if you want to deal with cases in which it is not defined by the C implementation, you can test with `#if defined NAN`.

Comment: It's a 20+ years old legacy code. I would avoid requesting a C 2018 for such a small thing as definition of NaN in it...

Comment: Oh, I missed that it's valid for C99 too

Answer (score 2):

If you can't rely on the existence of C99's `NAN` constant, another way to compute NaN is by subtracting Inf from Inf.  If your compiler supports infinity and NaN at all, `HUGE_VAL` should be a double-precision infinity.  Thus, I suggest something like

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const double qnan = HUGE_VAL - HUGE_VAL;

int main(void) {
    printf("qnan = %g (%a) isnan(qnan) = %d\n", qnan, qnan, isnan(qnan));
    return 0;
}
```

If the compiler doesn't support infinity and NaN, then `HUGE_VAL` will be the largest possible *finite* number and `HUGE_VAL - HUGE_VAL` will be zero, so you can check whether this worked with `assert(mynan != 0)`.